# Algebraic way for finding a transfer function of a filter

Tags: circuit-analysis, filter, transfer-function, active-filter, laplace-transform

I've the following filter and I tried to write the transfer function for it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWiyrd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And I wrote for the current nodes the following equations:

1. $$\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_1}{\frac{1}{\text{s}\text{C}_1}}+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}=0\tag1$$
2. $$\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_\text{out}}{\frac{1}{\text{s}\text{C}_3}}+\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}=0\tag2$$
3. $$\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}+\frac{\text{V}_3}{\frac{1}{\text{s}\text{C}_2}}=0\tag3$$
4. $$\text{V}_+=\text{V}_-\space\implies\space\text{V}_3=\text{V}_+=\text{V}_-=\text{V}_\text{out}\tag4$$

> Question: are my equations correct? And how can I find \$\frac{\text{V}_\text{out}}{\text{V}_\text{in}}\$ from this (if they are correct of coruse)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first node equation should be:

$$\frac{\text{V}_\text{1}-\text{V}_{in}}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_1}{\frac{1}{\text{s}\text{C}_1}}+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}=0\tag1$$
Rest are correct:
$$\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_\text{out}}{\frac{1}{\text{s}\text{C}_3}}+\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}=0\tag2$$
$$\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}+\frac{\text{V}_3}{\frac{1}{\text{s}\text{C}_2}}=0\tag3$$
$$V_3 = V_{out}\tag4$$
We can simplify (3) using (4)
$$\frac{\text{V}_{out}-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}+\frac{\text{V}_{out}}{\frac{1}{\text{s}\text{C}_2}}=0$$
$$\implies V_2 = V_{out}(1+\frac {R_3}{1/sC_2})\tag5$$
You can use (5) to eliminate \$V_2\$ from (1) and (2) to end up in two equations with 3 independent variables of form:
$$f(V_1,V_{in}, V_{out}) = 0 \tag6$$
$$g(V_1,V_{in}, V_{out}) = 0 \tag7$$
You can then find an expression for \$V_1\$ in terms of \$V_{in}\$ and \$V_{out}\$ from (6) as well as from (7). Equate both of them to get a final equation of form:
$$h(V_{in},V_{out}) = 0 $$
You can then sort out \$V_{out}/V_{in}\$ to derive the transfer function.

Answer (score -1):

Basically what you have are 5 unknown variables and 4 equations, allowing you to find an expression in the form of \$\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}\$.

Be carefull with Kirchhoffs' Current Law: You state that \$I_1 = 0\$ which is not true unless you consider that as beign the current flowing in/out of node \$I_1\$ through a virtual wire. You can nevertheless correctly state that $$\sum_{i}I_{n,i} = 0$$ where \$I_{n,i}\$ is the current \$I_i\$ flowing into node \$n\$. With this mentioned you can insert one equation into another like you would in a normal algebraic equation.

Comment: Ok, I know. I assume an ideal opamp. And this does not answer my question (because I'm asking IF my equations are correct?), but thank for the remark.

Comment: I know, because of eq. 4, that you are assuming an ideal opamp. Your equations seem correct, so using algebra you should be able to solve your problem?

Comment: I get a different result than they get in a different answer (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/338350/find-the-transfer-function-of-this-3th-order-filter/338449#338449 or https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/361665/finding-the-transfer-function-of-a-opamp-filter-circuit).

Comment: @Looper: your result in your previous thread is wrong. Post your result I will check it for you.

Comment: @Looper: This is my result (hope I didn't make any mistake).
https://ibb.co/hGgeAH

Comment: @Looper: just solve system of equations above.